# Color subtraction RBG or CIElab

Tags: java, android, algorithm, colors, rgb

I've read few topics here and according to answers there is no exact solution. Anyway lets assume we have RGB color picker (0-255,0-255,0-255) and two colors, one original unmixed and another mixed one, then how do I exactly subtract to find which one was added? Does it actually work as

> z - y = x ?

Are there any research formulas?

Another question is if apply CIElab tranformation to get hue saturation brightness then how do I apply these to subtract colors?

Comment: Semi related video regarding RGB computer color: [Computer Color is Broken](https://youtu.be/LKnqECcg6Gw) which may be useful.

Comment: The answer is that you have to reverse the mixing algorithm. But the problem is that some color mixing is not reversible (due in part to [arithmetic saturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic)). For example, consider that the color `z` can be produced by mixing `w` and `y`, and by mixing `x` and `y`. If you know `z` and `y`, then there's no way to know whether the third color was `w` or `x`.

Comment: @user3386109 never thought about it before, are there any kind of solution? I've read about modular one, but idk if it is appropriate.

would it be better to normalize all colors before comparing to one luminance first and then compare at max saturation, to compare without gray mixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean additive colour mixing?

In this case, just the light is added. So, it is just addition and subtraction of intensities of light, so RGB is fine. But you need linear colour space. So you need to "unapply" gamma, add or subtract, and apply again gamma.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Specification_of_the_transformation for the formula to apply Gamma and unapply it: `C` is channel (R, G, B, each), `C_linear` is linear space (where you can add and subtract intensities) and `C_srgb` is the channel value as we use on computers.  Note: you should divide and multiply with 255, to normalize values from 0 to 1.

For normal colour mixing (paints, inks, dyes, etc.), this is complex, but one could in such case, CIExyz is preferred: In fact on such space, the result of mixing is in the line between the two original chromacities.  Unfortunately, the model do not tell you where the result will be within such line. Usually more data about each colour is needed (often instead of the RGB triplet, a vector of about 60 items [so a data every 5nm])

Comment: Useful technique, thank you!
Few questions: sRGB is standard/ default we all have on devices, right?
Another: why CIExyz is superior to CIElab? Latter one has L close to human eye and enormous color space?
How do I exactly subtract color? there is formula on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space but it is about summing can I reverse it? also it has luminances L for each color, how do I acquire them? Are there White reference coords?
How exactly I get that vector?

Comment: sRGB is the standard used by HTML, and before that, the standard for computer screen (defined by Microsoft and Co. in 199x). CIExyz and CIELab are just different colour spaces, just different representation of the same. CIExyz is never used (but it is useful, as I wrote). CIExyY is more common (Y more intuitive). but usually we have just x,y on a figure (the standard figure for colour space comparison. xy is standard to define chromacities (e.g. for sRGB). To convert colour from one space to the other CIELab is used (Lab is also similar to video components).

Comment: White reference is given by the standard. sRGB has a different white than other standards (it depends also on expected luminosity of ambient, by viewer). see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB. L is defined with the white. Usually we define it as 1 or 100 or 255 (as reference, not absolute value). White is the more luminous point on your screen. But white is made with R,G,B (on normal screen), so you can calculate the maximum luminosity of every colour (on a screen), always compared with white luminosity.

Comment: Can you please explain why CIExyz mixing result is a line? According to formula I should get resulting color point coordinates (xmix,ymix). Also could you please explain Luminances in wiki mixing formula, are L-luminance and Y-luminance the same within it?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space (same link)

Comment: @JayJayAbrams:(linear) RGB and XYZ are linear combination of cone sensitivities, so mixing is linear [and transformation are just matrix multiplications]. The construction of xyz (using just X, or Y or Z, and with same denominator) keeps the mixing (but no more in the middle). Luminance: Y was defined to be similar to luminance, so they are very similar (Y was fixed, luminance is a physical quantity, so new data could slightly change it, but AFAIK it was keep). Warning: there are a lot of confusion about luminance (often used wrongly). Y' is not Y. Always check the definition in the standard.